# Evaluate entered digits for 4-digits starting with 0, consecutive or repeating

Tags: javascript

There is a point in our IVR that we ask our customers to create a PIN, however, we have restrictions around what the PIN can contain.  Which are, it can't start with a 0, can't be consecutive numbers(1234), or duplicate numbers together(5555).

The following is the check for what is being entered:

```
var pattern = "^(\\d)(?!\\1+$)\\d\{3\}$";
var str = {Data.Element.dig_NewPin.value}.toString();
pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
if(pattern.test(str)){
  lvValidNewPin = "Good";
} else {
  lvValidNewPin = "Bad";
}
```

When testing, numbers starting with 0, and consecutive numbers (1234) are passing as good.  The duplicate number (5555) are bad as expected.

What can be changed to have the 0XXX and consecutive entries equal bad?

Comment: You're better off using string manipulation to check this instead of patching together a regex no one can understand or read in a week, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks caTS!  I'm very new to any type of coding, so lots to learn on my end.  I'll search the site for string manipulation to handle this task.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything has to be a regex.

```
if (str[0] === '0') // bad
{...}
```

```
if (Number(str[0]) + 1 == str[1] && 
      Number(str[1]) + 1 == str[2] && 
      Number(str[2]) + 1 == str[3]
   ) {...} // bad
```

Even the length check is much easier to read with regular js

```
if ((new Set(str)).size != 4) {...} // bad
```

Comment: `str[0]+1` results in a string. Cast `str[0]` to a number first, or use `1+str[0]` instead. JS is weird.

Comment: isn't a string what we want here?

Comment: No, my point is that if `str` is `"123"`, for example, `str[0]+1` results in `"11"` and not `2`.

Comment: oh, forgot about that

Comment: Thanks nullptr and caTS for the suggestions, I appreciate your input.